# Laravel 7 change date format to timestamp

Tags: php, laravel

Hello so right now I have this data that i retrieved from the database table and the format is ["2021-08-17 23:13:15"] and i wish to change it into something like this 1629243333 (another data) because i want to get the difference in days between both time. I tried using the gettimeStamp() but it doesnt work.

```
$updateRaw = \DB::table('tickets')
        ->where('id', $ticket)
        ->pluck('updated_at');
```

the $updateRaw is the data with the date format. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: I got this error after trying that (Exception(code: 0): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ([\"2021-08-17 23:13:15\"]) at position 0 ([): Unexpected character at C:\\laragon\\www\\testing\\website\\vendor\
esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Traits\\Creator.php:85).

Line 85 is parent::__construct($time ?: 'now', static::safeCreateDateTimeZone($tz) ?: null);

Comment: use `value()` instead of pluck. example in the answer. `pluck()` is more usefull whern you have multiple rows as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Carbon do like this, if `update_at` column is not carbon instance;

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::parse($updateRaw[0])->timestamp;
```

if it is then simply do

```
$updateRaw[0]->timestamp;
```

for more : https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: I got this error using that. production.ERROR: Method Carbon\Carbon::parset does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Carbon\\Exceptions\\UnknownMethodException(code: 0): Method Carbon\\Carbon::parset does not exist.

Comment: i imported it and it still says  production.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parset does not exist.

Comment: how about using `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Comment: typo? parse instead of parset?

Comment: sorry my mistake updated answer it is `parse` not `parset` thanks @GertB.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use native strtotime() to convert datetime to unix timestamp

```
$updateRaw = \DB::table('tickets')
        ->where('id', $ticket)
        ->value('updated_at'); //use value to get first value directly

$timestamp = strtotime($updateRaw);
```